# DECISION TREE : How to calculated for repeat decision noded such as this picture (C5.0 Algorithm -Decision tree)

Tags: classification, cart, algorithms, decision-theory

[image]

I confused about decision tree such as this picture why repeat decision node.Could you please explain that decision tree. thank you

Comment: On this picture, the variable range was split into three subranges.

Answer (score 1):

The proportion of "open" responses apparently varies across the variable "added_date_m". In particular, the proportion appears to be extremely close to 100% if added_date_m is larger than 49. Moreover, if added_date_m is lower or equal 49 but larger than 26, the proportion is still high but not quite as close to 100%.

More generally, if there is a smooth or even linear relationship between the mean of the response variable and the regressor variable, then the tree will require repeated splits in the same variable to approximate this.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer here on StatsExchange so that it also is flagged as solved.